# Javascript Array[i] as a condition in loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying understand how the condition myArr[i] works. For some reason it evaluates to false when i is bigger than 2 which also happens to be the length of the array. 
Apparently myArr[i] is equal to i < myArr.length. Could someone explain?

```
let myArr = [[1, 3], [5, 2], [2, 1]]

for (let i = 0; myArr[i]; i++){
    console.log(i)  //Result: 0, 1, 2
}

let i = 0
while (myArr[i]){
    console.log(i)  ////Result: 0, 1, 2
    i++
}
```

Comment: No, it's not equal to `i < myArr.length`. Try iterating an array like `[{}, null, {}]` or `[true, false, true]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When indexing into an array, you will get an undefined result whenever you try an index that doesn't exist. Undefined implicitly converts to a "false-like" value.

Comment: Thx for that quick answer! You're totally right, why didn't I think about that.

Comment: You're explenation makes totally sense and when I console log Boolean(myArr[0]) I get "true" but for some reason I get false when I console log myArr[0] == true. Should't that be true?

Comment: Well, technically it's not equal to true, it's an array. If you want to convert an object/array's existence to a boolean, here's a little trick: !!myArr[0]

Comment: Also, if this answers your question, would you mind marking it as an answer to let people know we're not looking for one anymore?

Comment: Sure, I marked it as solved! Thx a lot for your answer and the little trick, exactly what I was looking for. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

No myArr[i] is not < the length of the array.

myArry[i] is a reference to whatever is in the memory slot of `i` Each section of the array is a pointer in memory.

So when you say myArry[2] you are asking the computer to fetch the value stored in the memory of slot 2 in the array. When you say myArry[3] you don't have anything stored in that memory slot, so it returns undefined.